# Reverse words of a sentence

Tags: ruby, string

I want to reverse a sentence. For example, my string is like follows.

```
 str = "I am a good boy"
```

I want the result `"boy good a am I"`. I can reverse the string by using built in Ruby methods like:

```
 str.split(" ").reverse.join(" ") #=> "boy good a am I"
```

Is there any way to do this without using Ruby built in methods?

Comment: That is not reversing a string. Describe it more appropriately.

Comment: I myself think your answer is already good enough. Maybe it's possible to use one method less here or there but the lack of readability will probably not be worth it.

Comment: If you are not using ruby built in methods, then how are you going to do it? Many people ask for the opposite; it is the first time I saw someone asking for this.

Comment: Just parse your string, delimit on spaces, then write a routine to return an array in the opposite order, and concatenate that array together as a string with spaces in between each element. Why is this a question?

Comment: *"Is there any way to do this without using Ruby built in methods?"* - you could use Perl or Python ;-)

Comment: Even '[]' is a method. :D

Comment: @Stefan or may be C? :)

Comment: The question should be more explicit as to use other languages - you will always end up using a method in Ruby. Even [] or + are methods in Ruby!

Answer (score 4):

Sure, there is the way. In fact my favorite way. You said you don't want to use Ruby's builtins. Well, we won't. What about native extensions? I know people love them.

**Firstly**, create `reverse/reverse.c` file. Most of the source I took [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-words-in-a-given-string/).

```
#include "ruby/ruby.h"

void reverseWords(char *s)
{
    char *word_begin = NULL;
    char *temp = s; 
    while( *temp )
    {
        if (( word_begin == NULL ) && (*temp != ' ') )
        {
            word_begin=temp;
        }
        if(word_begin && ((*(temp+1) == ' ') || (*(temp+1) == '\0')))
        {
            reverse(word_begin, temp);
            word_begin = NULL;
        }
        temp++;
    }
    reverse(s, temp-1);
}

void reverse(char *begin, char *end)
{
    char temp;
    while (begin < end)
    {
        temp = *begin;
        *begin++ = *end;
        *end-- = temp;
    }
}

VALUE reverse_words(VALUE str)
{
    char *s;
    s = RSTRING_PTR(str);
    reverseWords(s);
    return str;
}

void Init_reverse_words() 
{
    VALUE string = rb_const_get(rb_cObject, rb_intern("String"));
    rb_define_method(string, "reverse_words!", reverse_words, 0);
}
```

**Secondly**, create `reverse/extconf.rb` file:

```
require 'mkmf'
create_makefile('reverse_words')
```

**Thirdly**, in terminal cd to `reverse` folder and run:

```
$ ruby extconf.rb
$ make && make install
```

**Finally**, test it at `irb`.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'reverse_words'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> "foo bar baz".reverse_words!
=> "baz bar foo"
```

That's the way to reverse words order without using builtins.

Comment: This answer is amazing.

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse an Array by [pop](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-pop) ing each element into a new Array

```
arr, new_arr = ["I", "am", "a", "good", "boy"], []
for i in 0...arr.length do
   new_arr << arr[arr.length - 1 - i]
end
new_arr
# => ["boy", "good", "a", "am", "I"]
```

Comment: here also you are using ruby built in functions like pop. I want the solution without using it.

Comment: length is also a built in method isn't it ? Plus, you starts with an array instead of a string...

Answer (score 0):

TRy this

```
def reverse(string)
    reverse = ""
    index = 0
    while index < string.length
       reverse = string[index] + reverse
       index += 1
    end
    return reverse
end

reverse_sent = reverse(""I am a good boy"")
reverse_sent.split.map{|word| reverse(word)}.join(" ")
```

Comment: You used split and map and join methods

Answer (score 0):

You can not.

In ruby, you'll always end up using just an other methods, or reimplementing some that already exist (like other answer did).

In C maybe you could, using dynamic length array, but in ruby you MUST use the builtins methods.

Comment: Hm, he could create a native extension.

Comment: It's not ruby anymore then :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to do this without using Ruby built in methods?

No.

Ruby is an object-oriented language. In OO, you do things by calling methods. There is no other way to perform any action.

Okay, technically, there are *some* corners where Ruby is not object-oriented: `if`, `&&`, `||`, `and` and `or` have no corresponding methods. So, that's all you can use.